# What are the files in the phoneypot directory?

Tags: file-system, lineageos

I am running LineageOS 17.1 Lavender. Can anyone tell me the purpose of the files located in the `/phoneypot` directory in my Android device?

Answer (score 1):

I had an app called [Haven](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.havenapp.main) installed on my system, and it turns out that *phoneypot* directory is created and used by this app. Thanks to @beeshyams for the answer to my query.